# Help with Axis Placement when extruding

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I am just learning Blender.
I am going through the [second part of the coffee mug tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChPle-aiJuA).

The first part was good. I was able to follow it. Coming from SketchUp, it is taking some adjustment. But I am getting it.

I am just starting the second video. At the beginning, the instructor selects the top of the mug to extrude it. When he presses the E key and Enter, the red, green blue axis moves to the center of those vertices. That does not happen when I press the E key and Enter.

This is only 1:30 into the video.

How can I get the axis in the middle of this circle of vertices? 
The next step is to scale. I need the reference point in the middle of this circle of vertices. I cannot left-click accurately enough to position the axis/reference point.

I am using 2.69. The video uses 2.64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the [*Pivot point*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point) is set to [*Median Point*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point/Median_Point) (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>) or [*Bounding box center*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point/Bounding_Box_Center) (<kbd>,</kbd>) in *3D view > Header*:

[image]